# Auto generate builder skeleton from superclass (Lombok & Java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, builder, lombok

I would like to "generate" skeleton code from builder based on Java models. The reason for this is that we are having large nested data models which we would like to validate in our mocked repository tests and it´s a time-consuming process of creating them up.

So for example:

I would like to generate from this:

```
@Getter
@Builder
public class Widget {
    private final String name;
    private final int id;
}
```

To this:

```
Widget testWidget = Widget.builder()
  .name("")
  .id()
  .build();
```

And then fill it by myself with test data.

Do you have suggestions of Intellij plugins or anything please let me know, would save a lot of time for us.

Regards

Comment: I do not understand your use case. If you are familiar with TDD and you are using this builder to setup your test data, you should fill the Widget only with specific data, relevant for your test case.

Comment: In this data unit test I would like to test that our Mapper is parsing the data correctly. 

I have created a file containing json data.
During the test we parse that data and set it as response for MockWebServer.
Then we would like to fill a POJO object with the same data using builder and then validate the response from the mock server with the POJO.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no ready tool to generate the ready builder skeleton in IntelliJ IDEA. Please feel free to create a feature request for it in the YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237076 :)